# The update of a row using spring data jpa dose not work as expected when @Version annotation is used....?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Base entity which has a row-version field annotated with @Version

```
@Version
private Integer rowVersion;
```

I am trying to update an entity using the id value. I can update it using a reference by calling `findByID()` method and set each field manually and call `save()` method. But if I get an entity object with an Id, I expect to update the row in data base with that given Id.

When I use `@Version` annotation every time save an object with a given Id it creates a new row instead of updating the the row with given Id. If I remove the `@Version` annotation update works fine. 
I would like to know How can I update the database with managing the versions.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use the `javax.persistence.Version` annotation, not the Spring one.

Make sure all of your data is saved into the DB properly. (The version column MUST HAVE a value, it shouldn't be `null`) 
If you have some test data in the DB set the version field to 0 or 1 for them.

If the version field is `null` spring Data JPA assumes it's a new object and persists it, otherwise it merges it.

Comment: I am using the javax.persistence.Version. the problem is i can not update the row using the object i received from the front end side. I set the Id to ensure that it updates without creating a new one but it dose not work. but if I get the object using findByID() method and then manually set the all filds then it works. what might be wrong here

Comment: The front end MUST provide the version field too. If the version field is `null` in the request, response with an error message immediately. (Especially, because the version is also used during the update: The entry will be updated ONLY if the version is matches with the stored version.)

Comment: Is there any way i can update the row version from my back end side?

Comment: I am using a dto that dose not contain the rowVersion. I tried to set the value by getting the current object using findById() and then set the row version of that object to the new object got from front end side. but it makes the rowVersion field null and creates a new row

Comment: now Its working as you mentioned not setting the row version field was the problem. Thank you very much!!!!!!!